# What could cause a Flask server to become unresponsive after serving only one request?

Tags: python, flask

I have implemented a Flask server for an API and it is run without any error. However, in test time, it only works for the very first request and after that, it kind of freeze and does not respond anymore. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Please attach your code

Comment: Post your code and show your efforts.